# Как изменять значение в базе данных при регистрации?

Tags: python, sqlite, aiogram

Мне нужно изменять значение(0) на 1 в таблице когда человек заходит в бота и проходит небольшую регистрацию, сделать проверку по этому значению.

Вот моя попытка

```
def register(self):
    with self.connection:
        return self.cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET reg = ? WHERE user_id = ?", (1, user_id,))
```

в таблице столбец reg имеет INTEGET NO NULL DEFAULT 0

в боте

```
@dp.message_handler(commands = "start")
async def start(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer( "Добро пожаловать!")
    db.register(0,message.from_user.id)
```

Comment: Вы не написали, в чём собственно проблема, какая у вас ошибка. Но так то раз вы передаёте параметры функции `register` вы должны их указать в заголовке функции.

Comment: TypeError: register() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given ошибка

Comment: я вас понял и все получилось спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, чтобы вызывать метод с такими параметрами, нужно его описать соответственно:

```
def register(self, reg, user_id):
```

Хотя вы первый параметр (после `self`) и не используете, но я предположил, что он должен быть таким.